# Unable to change name of html elements of new row via JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html

HEY Guys Need a Little help here, 
I use addROW function to add a new row to the table but i want to change the name of the html elements of every new row.
CODE

```
function addRow(tableID) {

            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

            var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

            for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

                var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

                newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
                //alert(newcell.childNodes);
                switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                    case "text":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                            newcell.childNodes[0].name = "newratings" //this doesnt work

                            break;
                    case "a":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].value = "Delete Course";
                            break;
                    case "select-one":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                            newcell.childNodes[0].name = "newcourses"   //this doesnt work
                            break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: are you getting any error? what happens after this function?

Comment: the function works perfectly but when i check the name of the new html elements they remain thesame

Comment: is it going into the case? Did you give alert?

Comment: hoping you checked all as per the above comments. `use setAttributes('attrName', 'value')` this will work.

Comment: the setAttribute part is not working This is what I have tried      case "text":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                            newcell.childNodes[0].setAttribute('name','newrating');
                            break;

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered the use of the setAttribute function. Try this:

```
.....childNodes[0].setAttribute("name", "yourName");
```

It may require some more searching on your part to make it work for your example but its a start.

One thing to note is that child nodes will return a collection of all child node possibilities which could be tags, text nodes or comments so a better option would be to use getElementsByTagName() instead.

Comment: the setAttribute option also doesnt seem to be workingI tried this      case "text":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                            newcell.childNodes[0].setAttribute('name','newrating');
                            break;

Comment: The parameters in setAttribute should be enclosed in double quotes if that helps? Can you alert what element name you already have at that position? If you print out what options you have in your childnodes then you can see which ones you can change.

Comment: You could try this. var elementVar = newcell.childNodes[0].getElementsById("td")[0]; 
elementVar.setAttribute("name", "yourName");

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the example I have add to this answer.  I think it was setting the text elements name.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9mNwL/1/)

Comment: This sets the name of every cell in the row to same name, I intend to set them different